# SAS: Using the Put statement to create dynamic code

Tags: dynamic, sas

I'd like to create dynamic code using the `PUT` statement. According to this document from SUGI 29 (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/175-29.pdf),

```
put
"data XXXXX; "
/ 'infile "&datadir/&compid&filetype" missover ls=' tbla_fle
';' / 'input'
;
```

is equivalent to running

```
data onecomp ;
infile
"&datadir/&compid&filetype"
missover ls = 268 ;
input
```

However, when I try something similar to their example, the code enclosed in the `PUT` statement doesn't run and is instead written to the SAS Output Log:

```
data _NULL_;
put // "data put_test;" / "b=2;" / "run;";
run;

In Output Log:

data put_test;
b=2;
run;
```

I've checked the SAS documentation, and it seems that `PUT` is only used to "Write lines to the SAS log, to the SAS output window, or to an external location that is specified in the most recent FILE statement." Nowhere does it say that it can be used to create dynamically generated code.

I know that I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what. I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 4.1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use `put` to write your generated code to a file. You then `%include` the file into your SAS session to run it. What you're missing is a `file` statement and the `%include` directive.

```
data _null_;
    file 'temp.sas'; /* redirects put to a file instead of the SAS log */
    put
      "data XXXXX; "
      / 'infile "&datadir/&compid&filetype" missover ls=' tbla_fle
      ';' / 'input'
    ;
run;

%include 'temp.sas';
```